# How to set length for two-column CV

Tags: two-column, cv

I found a CV template and added some packages. However, I wonder why the length of 2 columns are short like the first column goes to half of the page and jumps to the second column. How can I make both columns go until the end of the page? 
Thanks!

```tex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,german,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{1cm}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{1em}


\title{Studentin}
\firstname{A}
\familyname{B}
\extrainfo{* Germany}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\linewidth-\leftskip-\rightskip-\separatorcolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth}

        \section{BERUFSERFAHRUNG}
        \cventry{ 01/2015 -- 09/2015}{}{Firma Tristar Catering Ltd, 
        }{}{}{Leitung eines Teams von 10 Wirtschaftsprüfer , und speichern Tierpfleger: Berichte Überprüfung, Verfahren einrichten, steuern Kosten unter Normen}

        \section{Education}
        \cvitem{Springfield High School}{High School Diploma}

        \section{Awards}
        \cvitem{1992}{Montgomery Burns Award for Outstanding Service in the Field of Excellence.}

    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: `multicol` automatically balances the columns, so that both (all) columns are equally filled. If you want to fill the left column completely and just then use the second column, you can replace `multicols` by `multicols*`.

Comment: @leandriis Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In the `multicols` environment columns are automatically balanced. This means that all columns are equally filled (the top  and  bottom  baselines  of  all columns align). If you prefer unbalanced columns (completely fill the leftmost column first) you can use the `multicols*` environment instead.